# Mock.Verify throws errors but Mock.Setup actually has data

Tags: unit-testing, mocking

I'm new to unit testing and Mocking data.  I have 2 mocked repo's that I've set up like this :

```
        [Test]
    public void TestRun()
    {

        _UserRepo.Setup(x => x.GetById(RequestCache, It.IsAny<Guid>())).Returns(new User
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid()
        });

        _repo.Setup(x => x.GetById<Company>(RequestCache, It.IsAny<Guid>())).Returns(new Company
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid()
        });


        var result = _query.Run(RequestCache);
        Assert.NotNull(result);
        Assert.IsFalse(result.HasErrorsOrWarnings());

        _UserRepo.Verify(x=> x.GetById(RequestCache, It.IsAny<Guid>()), Times.Once);
        _repo.Verify(x=> x.GetById<Company>(RequestCache, _id), Times.Once);
    }
```

When I debug I show that I do have a new user with a random guid and same with company.  Problem is when I verify that the repo's have been called I get an error expected 1 but was 0.

```
        _UserRepo.Verify(x=> x.GetById(RequestCache, It.IsAny<Guid>()), Times.Once);
        _repo.Verify(x=> x.GetById<Company>(RequestCache, It.IsAny<Guid>()), Times.Once);
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Show the test and what is being tested in a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Still not complete. how is the subject under test and its dependencies initialized/arranged. What does the method being tested look like? ie `Run`.